# Iterating through JSON objects even if key is missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops

I have a JSON have the following data:

```
        {
       "results":[
          {
             "name":"Sydney Showboats",
             "photos":[
                {
                   "photo_reference":"Pic062"
                }
             ]
          },
          {
             "name":"Blue Line Cruises"
          },
          {
             "name":"Rhythmboat Cruises",
             "photos":[
                {
                   "photo_reference":"Pic678"
                }
             ]
          },
          {
             "name":"Flying Fish Restaurant & Bar",
             "photos":[
                {
                   "photo_reference":"Pic345"
                }
             ]
          }
       ],
       "status":"OK"
    }
```

I'm trying to loop through this JSON to display every name value in the .name div and every image in the .photo div:

```
$.getJSON(jsonPlacesUrl, function(data) {
  $.each(data.results, function(index){
    $('.name').html('<p>' + data.results[index].name + '</p>');
    $('.photo').html('<img src="' + data.results[index].photos[0].photo_reference + '.jpg">');
  })
});
```

It works fine with the name value and works fine with the first image too. However, since there is no "photos" property in the second object, the script stops because of an

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

So is there a way to either:
Delete the objects which do not have the photos object nested inside? 
Use a more complex loop to iterate through the JSON and store every image available?
Any possible solution allowing me to display every image available dynamically?

If anyone can enlighten me it would be gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to make sure that the current object in the iteration contains that property. One way to check if an object contains a property is using the `in` operator.

```
$.getJSON(jsonPlacesUrl, function(data) {
  $.each(data.results, function(index){
    if ('photos' in data.results[index] && 'name' in data.results[index]){
      $('.name').html('<p>' + data.results[index].name + '</p>');
      $('.photo').html('<img src="' + 
      data.results[index].photos[0].photo_reference + '.jpg">');
    }
 })
```

});

[Documentation for in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

Comment: This doesn't deserve a random downvote any more than mine does, it's a perfectly reasonable solution. +1 :)

Comment: Both are good solutions to this problem. I'm not sure why they were down voted @msanford .

Comment: Someone had a bad day. Whatever. Note that there is also an accessor on `name` so you might want to add that guard as well, just for completeness.

Comment: Edited and added check for the other property. @Stephan great! :)

Answer (score 1):

Any time you have an *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prop-name' of undefined"* you have a situation in which you need to add a [guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)) against [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof):

```
$.getJSON(jsonPlacesUrl, function(data) {
  $.each(data.results, function(index){
    if (typeof data.results[index].photos !== "undefined" && typeof data.results[index].name !== "undefined") { // <- Here
      $('.name').html('<p>' + data.results[index].name + '</p>');
      $('.photo').html('<img src="' + data.results[index].photos[0].photo_reference + '.jpg">');
    }
  })
});
```

If you need to ensure that ancestors are defined, it can be chained, like:

```
if (typeof a !== "undefined" && typeof a.b !== "undefined" && typeof a.b.c !== "undefined")
```

and so on.

Also note Pablo's answer featuring `in` which is more concise.

Alternatively, you *can* [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) your list:

```js
const json_parsed = {
  "results": [{
      "name": "Sydney Showboats",
      "photos": [{
        "photo_reference": "Pic062"
      }]
    },
    {
      "name": "Blue Line Cruises"
    },
    {
      "name": "Rhythmboat Cruises",
      "photos": [{
        "photo_reference": "Pic678"
      }]
    },
    {
      "name": "Flying Fish Restaurant & Bar",
      "photos": [{
        "photo_reference": "Pic345"
      }]
    }
  ],
  "status": "OK"
}

clean_list = json_parsed['results'].filter(item => typeof item.photos !== "undefined" && typeof item.name !== "undefined");

console.dir(clean_list);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this very complete answer, this is really helpful since I struggled a lot on this issue!